# Fullscreen video as site header background

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

I'm having problems trying to fix this problem. I have a client that required that the site header need to have a video as background with a dark layer on it and over the video & overlay there will also be some texts (like `h1`,`span`, etc).
My attempts so far didn't work.

I googled and found some old questions but none of them worked.

The concept is really simple. I have 3 div's in my section called "hero":

- video-overlay : this is the dark overlay for the video
- video-wrap : this contains the video element
- hero-content : this contains the `h1`, `span`, etc. elements that are gonna be displayed over the video.

**HTML**

```
<section class="hero" id="hero">
    <div class="video-overlay"></div>

    <div class="video-wrap">
        <video autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" poster="media/img/vid-placeholder.jpg" class="bg-video">
                <source src="media/vid/amazon.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>

    <div class="row hero-content text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="media/img/logo-white-2x.png" class="logo animated fadeInDown" />
            <h1 class="animated fadeInDown">The leading, most customer friendly and hassle-free refund service since 2005.</h1>
            <a href="#buy" class="use-btn animated fadeInUp">Claim now</a> <a href="#about" class="learn-btn animated fadeInUp">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
   position: relative;
   color: #fff;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.video-overlay {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.video-wrap {
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: -999;
}
.bg-video {
   min-height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: -999;
}
.hero-content {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 5;
}
```

With this code I get this result: http://prntscr.com/8y3uau 
with the text displayed under the video as its shown here: http://prntscr.com/8y3uok

**[Here](http://family.olegnax.com/forest/index.html)'s a good template that you can use as example to understand how the video & texts must be displayed.**

I also want the video to be responsive.

Other information:

- I use Bootstrap for the responsive part of the site
- Video could also be found on youtube, so if you have an idea with a youtube video instead than using a `<video>` tag it's alright.

Thank you very much to anyone in advance!

Comment: You should use position absolute for your overlay and media queries for mobile part. That much I can help you. I won't do your job.

Comment: Not sure about the issue, a JSFiddle would help understand. But for what I can see, it looks like you have the text (.hero-content) underneath the full-page video, so maybe positioning the video (.video-wrap) as absolute will solve the stacking issue.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. I solved the problem so I will answer this question showing the solution that worked for me, but thank you again because your suggestions drove me in the right direction! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the suggestions I received and played a little bit with the `CSS` and finally solved the problem using the following code. Thank you both again @Ionut and @Leuquim!

**HTML**

```
<section class="hero" id="hero">
    <div class="video-overlay"></div>
    <div class="video-wrap">
        <video autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" poster="media/img/vid-placeholder.jpg" class="bg-video">
            <source src="media/vid/amazon.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row hero-content text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <img src="media/img/logo.png" class="logo animated fadeInDown" />
                <h1 class="animated fadeInDown top-bottom-borders">The leading, most customer friendly and hassle-free refund service since 2005.</h1>
                <a href="#buy" class="use-btn animated fadeInUp">Claim now</a> <a href="#about" class="learn-btn animated fadeInUp">Learn more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 800px;
    color: #fff;
}
.video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 1;
}
.video-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.bg-video {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    z-index: -999;
}
.hero-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 120px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

**NOTE:** My page also uses `Bootstrap` for the responsive part (grid-system).